# How to pass children to react native ViewPager?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm quite new to react-native. Here Card is a view component having nothing special but text view with dimensions as `flex: 1` I've my `App.js` as:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {


  constructor(props: props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ViewPager style={styles.pager} children={Card,Card,Card} count={3} height={100} width={100} selectedIndex={0} initialPage={0}>

        </ViewPager>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using the F8 app ViewPager which is made for both ViewPager & ScrollView for Android & iOS respectively. Which is as here (not inserting code here to keep it clean): [ViewPager Component In F8 App](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/common/ViewPager.js)

So what I need to know is how to pass a children to the ViewPager from my App.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for or what? Hope it will help you for some idea.

> App.js passing value as View and Text

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ViewPager style={styles.pager}>

          // Children Array or any View as you prefer //
          <Card>
            <View>
              <Text>Hello</Text>
            </View>
          </Card>
          /////// End Block /////

        </ViewPager>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> ViewPager.js get value as props from App.js

```
export default class ViewPager extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        // these all props that pass from APP component
        {this.props.children}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```